# git revert file to previous commit after changing it's path

Tags: git

I have a file `./new-path/file.java` which is controlled by Git. In an earlier commit (`<SHA-1>`) it's path was `./older-path`. Now I want to restore it's older content as was committed in `<SHA-1>`.

I can restore that file by doing `git checkout <SHA-1> -- ./older-path/file.java` and then copy it's content to `./new-path/file.java`. But I have to do above steps for multiple older commits and this way is not appropriated. How I can do it **directly** by Git?

Comment: `git show <SHA-1>:older-path/file.java > new-path/file.java`?

Comment: @melpomene Thank you, it works perfectly. I could accept it if you posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, but that's not actually a problem.

If you ask Git to check it out *by name* you will get the old name.

If you ask Git to show you the *content*, you do this by the old name, and the content goes to standard output, which you can redirect, but *not* using Git.  So you can do it directly, but not directly *by Git*:

```
git show <hash>:./older-path/file.java > new-path/file.java
```

Note that `git show` will not apply filters (including end of line filtering).  Adding `--textconv` is supposed to cause it to do such conversions, but this is not working in my experiments (with Git 2.19.0).  An alternative is to use `git cat-file --filters <hash>:<path>`, which does seem to work.  However, the filters used are those defined in the *current* `.gitattributes` rather than the `.gitattributes` associated with the specified commit.